# robot_state_publisher

Tags: robot-state-publisher, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i m installing robot_model pkg but robot_state_publisher is not installing.....everything is installed but robot_state_publisher is not installing in electric...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56631/robot_state_publisher/) by [rajanseeker](https://answers.ros.org/users/4319/rajanseeker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using the package from source? If so, make sure you download the electric version

---

Originally posted by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) with karma: 528 on 2014-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0